# Export a Chartist chart to pdf document (jspdf)

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, chartist.js

I'm in a situation were I need to output a chart into a javascript-generated pdf document using **jspdf**.

I want to convert the charts that are displayed on my website. 
I'm using Chartist for this.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

you can check out the addHTML function for jsPDF, it should give you a clean copy of the canvas

```
const pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4')
const chartistChart = document.getElementById('your-chartist-chart')
const previewPane = document.getElementById('preview-pane')

// addHTML is marked as deprecated, see links below for further information
pdf.addHTML(chartistChart, function() {
    // Get the output pdf data URI
    const outputString = pdf.output('datauristring')
    // Changes the src to new data URI
    previewPane.attr('src', outputString)
})
```

- https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML
- Issues on Github about deprecation, and future changes

  - https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/944
  - https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1176